# Deriving state from a useStates instead of store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

Afternoon fine people of the internet.

I'm building a little react component that will be standalone.
ie. not part of a larger app with a redux store.

I'm using a few `useState`s to hold some states, and I'd like to derive some additional data from those states.

```js
export function useNeatoThing() {
  const [datasetA, setDtasetA] = useState();
  const [datasetB, setDtasetB] = useState();

  fetch("apiA") ~~ pseudocode ~~> setDtasetA(data)
  fetch("apiB") ~~ pseudocode ~~> setDtasetB(data)

  const [myDerivedThing, setMyDerivedThing] = useState<number | undefined >()
  
  return {myDerivedThing, data: {datasetA, datasetB}}
}
```

I'm wondering what the best pattern is.

I would very much like to avoid using a useEffect to do the derivation.
This just feels clunky:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (datasetA && datasetB) {
    setMyDerivedThing(datasetA.alpha * datasetB.gamma)
  }    
}, [datasetA, datasetB] )
```

Am I stressing over nothing or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: read about useMemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `useEffect` to set a derived state. You shouldn't be having a state that is derived from state or props in the first place. Just calculate it on render. If it's an expensive calculation, use `useMemo` to memoize the operation. So your code should be

```
export function useNeatoThing() {
  const [datasetA, setDatasetA] = useState();
  const [datasetB, setDatasetB] = useState();

  fetch("apiA")~~~~> setDtasetA(data)
  fetch("apiB")~~~~> setDtasetB(data)

  const derivedThing = useMemo(() => {
      if (datasetA && datasetB) 
      return datasetA.alpha * datasetB.gamma;
   }, 
    [datasetA, datasetB])
  
  return {state, available, myDerivedThing, data: {datasetA, datasetB}}
}
```

Using `useEffect` for it makes it more complicated than necessary. It is inefficient too: it does an entire render pass with a stale value for the derived value, then immediately re-renders with the updated value.

As a rule, when you can derive something from state or props, [you should not put it in a state](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-redundant-state).

Comment: Ah, very nice. Im busy refactoring from classes and forgot all about on render. Thanks!